# Inherited constructors, default constructor and visibility

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, default-constructor, inherited-constructors

As stated by [[namespace.udecl]/18](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#18):

> [...] A using-declaration that names a constructor does not create a synonym; instead, the additional constructors are accessible if they would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class, and the accessibility of the using-declaration is ignored. [...]

Because of that, the following code does not compile:

```
class B { protected: B(int) { } };
class D: B { using B::B; };
int main () { D d{0}; }
```

It returns an error that is more or less the same with all the major compilers:

> declared protected here

On the other side, the following code compiles:

```
class B { protected: B() { } };
class D: B { using B::B; };
int main () { D d{}; }
```

Shouldn't it fail to compile instead for the same reasons that lead to an error in the previous example?
What does it allow it to compile?

Comment: Hint: `D` doesn't have a user-declared constructor.

Comment: @T.C. I thought the same, but _the accessibility of the using-declaration is ignored_, so shouldn't the default constructor be inherited and protected in the second case?

Comment: OK, another hint. What does [class.ctor]/4 say happens if the class has no user-declared constructor? And how does that interact with the base class constructor, given [namespace.udecl]/15?

Comment: Incidentally, only Clang 3.9 implements the [P0136R1](http://wg21.link/P0136R1) semantics (which you are quoting). The old rules simply don't inherit the default constructor.

Comment: @T.C. Thus, your are implicitly saying that default constructors are not inherited, even the user defined ones. Or better, inherited constructors do not participate when we look for use-defined constructors. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the 2nd case, *inheriting constructor* doesn't take effect. According to the rules of [deleted implicitly-declared default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_default_constructor), that in the 2nd case class `D` doesn't violate (there's a well-formed `B::B()` for `D`); the compiler will declare a default constructor as an inline public member for `D`, which makes `D d{};` work well.

> ...
>
> `T` has a direct or virtual base which has a deleted default constructor, or it is ambiguous or inaccessible from this constructor.
>
> ...

For the 1st case, [inheriting constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) takes effect:

(emphasis mine)

> If overload resolution selects an inherited constructor, it is
> accessible if it would be accessible when used to construct an object
> of the corresponding base class: **the accessibility of the
> using-declaration that introduced it is ignored**.
>
> **If overload resolution selects one of the inherited constructors when
> initializing an object of such derived class, then the Base subobject
> from which the constructor was inherited is initialized using the
> inherited constructor**, and all other bases and members of Derived are
> initialized as if by the defaulted default constructor (default member
> initializers are used if provided, otherwise default initialization
> takes place).

Then it fails because of the access isolation.

Comment: The rule about copy/move comes from [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#4), but from where it comes the rule about default one?

Comment: @skypjack The point is that a default constructor will be generated for class `D` in 2nd case, which will take effect other than *inheriting constructor*. Answer fixed.

Answer (score 6):

```
class B { protected: B() { } };
class D: B { using B::B; };
int main () { D d{}; }
```

`D` has no user-defined constructor in this case, so the compiler generates one (public) for you that calls `B::B` (but not because of the `using`, that has no effect in this case), that compiler-generated constructor is then called by main.

```
class B { protected: B(int) { } };
class D: B { using B::B; };
int main () { D d{0}; }
```

Even though `D` has no user-defined constructor here, the compiler-generated one is implicitly deleted because `B` only has a constructor that takes an `int`. `D` does also have a constructor that takes an `int` (`using` did that) but this constructor is marked `protected` and thus inaccessible by `main`.